# Hyper-V won't start - Not enough storage available to complete this application

Tags: windows-8, virtualization, hyper-v

on windows 8.1 Pro 64bit

when in Hyper-V Manager click Start Service, after a while (cca 60s) new event apears in event log - System saying:

> The Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service terminated with the following error: 
>   Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

- I get the same result when just trying to start the service manually
- all virtualizartion is enabled in BIOS
- all latest updates installed
- I did try to remove and the install Hyper-V again (yes, with reboots and etc.)
- running Hyper-V Manager as admin is no different
- as per some sugestions on web, I did run chkdsk on hdd's, but no difference
- there is 100GB spage left on c drive (if this make any difference ...)

Any ideas please? Thank you

Comment: How much space so you have on any other disks that might be connected and 100GB is the system disk right?

Comment: The other drive has 500GB spare...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an aswer to the question, but it is a workaround to my problem.

1. Uninstall completelly Hyper-V from OS.
2. Download and install Oracle's VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/) instead ...

...